# ndk-stack give me only have libc frame

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crash

I'm working with ndk develop, and it crashed when running, i get the info from logcat, and ndk-stack it, got this:

```
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 2418):     #00  pc 000221a8  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 2418):     #01  pc 00013265  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 2418):     #02  pc 00013479  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 2418):     #03  pc 000121af  /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 2418):     #04  pc 00021a5c  /system/lib/libc.so   (abort+4)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   ( 2418):     #05  pc 000c0d58  /data/app-lib/com.crossui.morningrout-2/libMorningRout.so (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+344): Routine __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() at /s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.8/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
```

here have not the frame of my so, the first frame is vterminate.cc:95, then, what can i do to find the bug?

**EDIT**:

```
03-10 18:05:16.810: A/libc(21995): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000055eb (code=-6), thread 22289 (Thread-58801)
03-10 18:05:16.860: I/DEBUG(2418): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-10 18:05:16.860: I/DEBUG(2418): Build fingerprint: 'Huawei/H60-L01/hwH60:4.4.2/HDH60-L01/CHNC00B313:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys'
03-10 18:05:16.860: I/DEBUG(2418): Revision: '0'
03-10 18:05:16.860: I/DEBUG(2418): pid: 21995, tid: 22289, name: Thread-58801  >>> com.crossui.morningrout <<<
03-10 18:05:16.865: I/DEBUG(2418): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
03-10 18:05:16.880: I/dalvikvm-heap(23060): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.969MB for 821860-byte allocation
03-10 18:05:16.960: I/dalvikvm-heap(23060): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.154MB for 767792-byte allocation
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     r0 00000000  r1 00005711  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     r4 00000006  r5 00000000  r6 00005711  r7 0000010c
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     r8 0000004e  r9 00000047  sl 7638fbe4  fp 7638eed8
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     ip 7ade9fb0  sp 766f7870  lr 400cd269  pc 400dc1a8  cpsr 000f0010
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d0  6461623a3a647473  d1  74705f6b6165775f
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d2  0000000000000061  d3  0000000000000e64
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d4  fffffffffffff000  d5  ffffffffffffffc0
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d6  00000000000a3124  d7  0000000000000e00
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d16 0000000000002000  d17 0000000000001000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d18 0000000000001000  d19 0000000000000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d20 000000000003b800  d21 0000000000000e00
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000fff
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d26 404cc05a40000000  d27 401711686c800000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d28 3ff0000000000000  d29 000000776705b005
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     d30 0000000000000001  d31 4000000000000000
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     scr 20000010
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418): backtrace:
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     #00  pc 000221a8  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     #01  pc 00013265  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     #02  pc 00013479  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     #03  pc 000121af  /system/lib/libc.so
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     #04  pc 00021a5c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     #05  pc 000c0d3c  /data/app-lib/com.crossui.morningrout-1/libMorningRout.so (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+344)
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418): stack:
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7830  78c0786c  [anon:libc_malloc]
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7834  78bd68c0  [anon:libc_malloc]
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7838  766f7868  [stack:22289]
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f783c  7643bb54  /data/app-lib/com.crossui.morningrout-1/libMorningRout.so (CrossApp::CAImage::setShaderProgram(std::shared_ptr<CrossApp::CAGLProgram> const&))
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7840  00000003  
03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7844  02cf0a94  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7848  40105224  /system/lib/libc.so
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f784c  02cf0a94  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7850  0000000b  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7854  00000001  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7858  00000015  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f785c  7251acd8  [anon:libc_malloc]
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7860  00000001  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7864  400f4929  /system/lib/libc.so (write+12)
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7868  401051d0  /system/lib/libc.so
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f786c  7251acd8  [anon:libc_malloc]
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     #00  766f7870  00000006  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7874  00000000  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7878  00005711  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f787c  7ade9fb0  [anon:libc_malloc]
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7880  7ade9fb0  [anon:libc_malloc]
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7884  400cd269  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     #01  766f7888  00000006  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f788c  00000000  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7890  765844d8  /data/app-lib/com.crossui.morningrout-1/libMorningRout.so
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f7894  400cd47d  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+14)
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     #02  766f7898  766f78a4  [stack:22289]
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):          766f789c  400cc1b3  /system/lib/libc.so
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418): memory near r1:
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000056f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005700 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005710 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005720 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005730 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005740 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005750 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005760 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005770 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005780 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005790 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418): memory near r6:
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000056f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005700 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005710 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005720 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005730 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005740 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005750 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005760 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005770 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005780 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     00005790 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     000057e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418): memory near sl:
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fbc4 1affffaf eaffffda e3a02000 e3a03002  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fbd4 e1a0000c e88a000c e28dd02c e8bd8ff0  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fbe4 e59f318c e92d40f0 e08f3003 e5d32000  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fbf4 e59f4180 e3520000 e08f4004 e24dd00c  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc04 1a00002b e3a05001 e5c35000 eb0021ee  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc14 e3500000 0a000048 e5900004 e3a01000  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc24 e5d03000 e3e02000 e353002a 00806005  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc34 11a06000 e28d3008 e5232004 e1a00006  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc44 e1a02001 eb002182 e59f312c e3a01001  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc54 e7944003 e3a02030 e28450a8 e1a03005  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc64 e1a07000 e59f0114 e08f0000 ebff9e51  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc74 e59d3004 e3530000 01a01005 11a01005  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc84 01a00007 11a00006 ebff9e4d e59f00f0  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fc94 e28430a8 e08f0000 e3a01001 e3a02002  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fca4 ebff9e44 e59d3004 e3530000 0a000009  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638fcb4 ebfffce1 e59f30c0 e59f00c8 e7943003  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418): memory near fp:
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638eeb8 e1a04001 e1a05000 ebfffccd e3740001  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638eec8 0a000000 ebfffb55 e1a00005 ebfffc21  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638eed8 e92d4008 e59f3008 e79f3003 e5930000  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638eee8 ebffffed 0023e1ec e92d4008 e12fff30  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638eef8 ebfffff6 e92d4008 e59f3008 e79f3003  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef08 e5930000 ebfffff7 0023e1cc e59f3010  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef18 e79f3003 e5932000 e5830000 e1a00002  
03-10 18:05:16.995: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef28 e12fff1e 0023e1b4 e59f3010 e79f3003  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef38 e5932000 e5830000 e1a00002 e12fff1e  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef48 0023e19c e3500001 e92d4010 8a000008  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef58 e511301c e2814058 e3530000 0a000001  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef68 e1a00004 e12fff33 e1a00004 e8bd4010  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef78 eafffaa3 e5110014 ebffffc7 e92d4ff8  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef88 e1a04000 e1a06001 e1a07002 ebfffd42  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638ef98 e59f2094 e59f1094 e79f2002 e592a000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7638efa8 e59f208c e79f1001 e591b000 e3a0e055  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418): memory near ip:
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7ade9f90 7767f008 00000000 00001000 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7ade9fa0 7767f008 00000438 000006a5 00000029  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7ade9fb0 401091d8 401091d8 6e65706f 472f6c67  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7ade9fc0 7275534c 65636166 77656956 00726500  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7ade9fd0 00000028 00000062 7ade9ef0 7ade9e28  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7ade9fe0 00000000 00000000 0000010c 765eefc8  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7ade9ff0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea010 00000000 00000000 77642380 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea020 00001000 00000000 77642380 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea030 00000000 0000002b 00000001 765d7c04  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea050 6863756f 67726154 00000028 0000100b  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea060 00000000 792bfb40 00000000 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea070 00000000 00000000 765eaac0 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     7adea080 7adec000 7adec000 0000000a 0018400f  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418): memory near sp:
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7850 0000000b 00000001 00000015 7251acd8  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7860 00000001 400f4929 401051d0 7251acd8  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7870 00000006 00000000 00005711 7ade9fb0  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7880 7ade9fb0 400cd269 00000006 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7890 765844d8 400cd47d 766f78a4 400cc1b3  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f78a0 40105224 ffffffdf 0000000a 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f78b0 40105224 4011332c 0000000a 4010517c  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f78c0 00000001 400dba60 00005711 7638fd40  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f78d0 7ade32b8 00000000 765c2088 7ade32b8  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f78e0 7ade3260 765c2088 763ca504 7638eeac  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f78f0 765ce00c 7638eeec 00000000 7638f034  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7900 765cdbd8 78fbb00c 78fbaff8 78fbb000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7910 790f9370 766f79d0 42c80000 00000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7920 00000000 763812e8 00000000 7643bdb0  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7930 78fbaffc 00000000 00000000 78fbaff8  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     766f7940 00000000 79158dfc 790f9370 7643ded4  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418): code around pc:
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc188 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc198 ea006f65 e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc1a8 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc1b8 ea006f5d e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc1c8 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc1d8 ea006f55 e3510000 0a006734 e710f110  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc1e8 e12fff1e e3510000 0a006730 e1a02000  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc1f8 e710f110 e0612190 e12fff1e e1520003  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc208 8a00008c f5d1f040 e92d4001 e3520010  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc218 3a000024 e2603000 e213300f 0a00000e  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc228 e0422003 e1b0cf83 44d1e001 44c0e001  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc238 24d1c001 24d1e001 24c0c001 24c0e001  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc248 e1b0ce83 aa000001 f4a1030d f480031d  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc258 3a000001 f421070d f400071d e2522040  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc268 3a000006 f421020d f421420d f5d1f100  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400dc278 e2522040 f400022d f400422d 2afffff8  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418): code around lr:
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd248 447b4b13 42b3e010 4812d10e 44786a1e  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd258 ec90f7fb e9d8f00d 46224631 ef9af00e  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd268 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd278 44782403 ec7ef7fb f001e002 6804fa1b  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd288 fa18f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003c162  
03-10 18:05:17.000: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd298 0003c156 0003c14e 0003c12a bf7ef7ff  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd2a8 4a3e4b3d 43f0e92d 4606b08b 447b460d  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd2b8 6823589c 930946a1 f9fcf001 8000f8d0  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd2c8 d0482d00 f00f4628 280fff09 d8444604  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd2d8 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8a2f00d  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd2e8 d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debc2  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd2f8 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd308 4a2aec3a 46332120 447aa801 fa88f013  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd318 a8012101 fd16f01a 46061c42 e011d104  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd328 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f0274622  
03-10 18:05:17.005: I/DEBUG(2418):     400cd338 1c43faf1 d11e4607 f9bcf001 29046801
```

Is there something in the log that ndk-stack not found?
thank you for your help!

Comment: From the logcat fragment I see, it's like the thread 22289 is aborting, but there may be (should be) a cause that aborts the execution. It does not necessarily belong to the same thread. One of such reasons could be OutOfMemory condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error with write log, it's because that: I call shared_from_this() in class destructor, after delete the line, all runs ok. thank you for your help!~

Answer (score 0):

find the location with your object file and address. 
(with not stripped object file)

It will show you the func and you will get clue to look at.

> 03-10 18:05:16.990: I/DEBUG(2418):     #05  pc **000c0d3c**  /data/app-lib/com.crossui.morningrout-1/**libMorningRout.so** (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+344)

(at directory of libMorningRout.so)

> addr2line -f -e **libMorningRout.so 0x000c0d3c**

Comment: the cmd give me :    _ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv
/s/ndk-toolchain/src/gcc/gcc-4.8/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95,    file: vterminate.cc line:95  is not my file , it is stl's      and this result have given me by ndk-stack, i think ndk-stack already call the addr2line tool.

Comment: The entire problem is that it only includes this stack frame, which doesn't tell you anything but that you're in the error handler.  It doesn't have the actual stack trace before that.  (You don't need to look at the address to tell that--it tells you it's in __verbose_terminate_handler right at the end of the line.)